# Como trazer duas colunas com resultados diferentes

Tags: sql

Estou querendo montar uma visão do total de projetos *Ativos* e *Encerrados*.

Tenho uma tabela `projetos` com os campos `nome`, `descricao`, `ativo` (pode ser S ou N)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM projetos WHERE ativo = 'S'
```

Ele me retorna o total de projetos ativos.

Existe alguma forma de trazer o total de projetos ativos e encerrados numa mesma consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) pra isso:

```
SELECT ativo as 'Situacao', COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM projetos GROUP BY ativo
```

Como você tem duas possíveis situações pra `ativo` ('S' e 'N'), ele retornará o total dos que estão 'S' em uma linha e dos que estão 'N' na outra.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu!!

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT sum(ativo = 'S') as TotalAtivo,
sum(ativo = 'N') as TotalEncerrado
FROM projetos 
WHERE ativo in('S','N')
```